# Find matrix $x, y, z$ from its eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> If I were given a matrix $A$,
> $$ A =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 5 & -2 & 3 \\
> 0 & y & 0 \\
> x & 7 & z \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> with corresponding eigenvalues $1, 7,$ and $−4$, respectively, find $x, y,$ and $z$.

I am familiar with finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors for matrices, but I'm not sure how to find $x, y, z$ for the matrix itself from the given eigenvalues. I'm currently stuck on using the determinant formula for each eigenvalues.
$$\begin{split}
0&=\det(A−I)\\
0&=\det(A−7I)\\
0&=\det(A+4I)\\
\end{split}$$

Comment: Compute $\det(A - \lambda I)$ and note that the $3$ solutions (in $\lambda$) must be $1, 7, -4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(A-\lambda I)=(5-\lambda)(y-\lambda)(z-\lambda)-3x(y-\lambda)=(y-\lambda)(\lambda^2-(5+z)\lambda+5z-3x)$.  This polynomial in $\lambda$ has roots $1, 7, -4$.

The root of the linear term is $y$.  If $y=-4$, the remaining roots are $1, 7$, which would mean $5+z=8$ and $5z-3x=7$, so $z=3, x=\frac 83$.

If $y=1$, the remaining roots are $7, -4$, which would mean $5+z=3$ and $5z-3x=-28$, so $z=-2, x=6$.

If $y=7$, the remaining roots are $1, -4$, which would mean $5+z=-3$ and $5z-3x=-4$, so $z=-8, x=-12$.

Confirm (by plugging them into the matrix and taking the determinant of $A-\lambda I$) that all three of these values for $(x, y, z)$ give you the required eigenvalues and you're done.